# MockMvc throws HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException Status expected: 201 but was 415

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I'm testing an api endpoint and MockMvc throws org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException Status expected:<201> but was:<415>
Read all SO about similar problems - always solution is in content-type,  but not in this case )
What is strange, I cannot see in MockHttpServletResponse's headers application/json.

Controller:

```
public static final String MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
@PostMapping(value = "/api/Register", consumes = MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, produces = MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> register(@RequestBody Map<String, String> jsonMap) {
  ...
  Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
  MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType("application", "json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8));
  headers.setContentType(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8);
  ...
  return new ResponseEntity<>(new Gson().toJson(responseMap), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void Register_phoneNumber_returnOk() throws Exception {
  Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
  body.put("phone", "1112223344");
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(body);
  MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = post("/api/Register");
  request.content("{\"phone\":\"1112223344\"}");
  request.accept(MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
  request.contentType(MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
  mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

Error:

```
WARN 6188 --- [main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=utf-8' not supported]

    MockHttpServletRequest:
          HTTP Method = POST
          Request URI = /api/Register
           Parameters = {}
              Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=utf-8", Accept:"application/json;charset=utf-8"]
                 Body = {"phone":"1112223344"}
        Session Attrs = {}

    Handler:
                 Type = ru.controllers.MainController
               Method = ru.controllers.MainController#Register(Map)

    Async:
        Async started = false
         Async result = null

    Resolved Exception:
                 Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

    ModelAndView:
            View name = null
                 View = null
                Model = null

    FlashMap:
           Attributes = null

    MockHttpServletResponse:
               Status = 415
        Error message = null
              Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Accept:"application/octet-stream, text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, multipart/mixed, */*"]
         Content type = null
                 Body = 
        Forwarded URL = null
       Redirected URL = null
              Cookies = []


    java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<415>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was quite simple.

Service with `@MockBean` annotation in test class was creating entities and saving them to db, then controller was returning entity id, that did NPE in `entity.getId()` and, of course, HTTP 415 in rest controller's test method. At the same time while testing in real db, postman did not show an error, because service layer always returned real id in `.getId()` method.
After i modified service layer code to check entity for null, problem was gone.